# Puncuation causes an error

Tags: python

Hello I got a small block of code that when run with the test phrase I get an error when the code hits the punctuation.  I think that the value of word is null but I tried to cast that to a string to prevent getting the error IndexError.  I have stepped through the program and am getting a value for word of '' instead of ' ' and would like to know the difference so I can fix this issue.  The code works with all letters.

```
word = ''
quote = input('enter a 1 sentence quote, non-alpha words: ').lower()
for character in quote:
    if character.isalpha() == True:
        word += character
    else:
        if str(word[0]) >= 'h':
            print(word.upper())
            word = ''

        else:
            word = ''
```

Sample Input:Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart
Desired Output:With all the capitalized words on their own line.
WHERESOEVER
YOU
WITH
YOUR
HEART

Comment: What exactly is a "none letter"?

Comment: Please post the entire exception, not just a description of it.

Answer (score 2):

`''` is a perfectly valid string. You don't need to "cast" it, or anything of the sort.

But it's an *empty* string. So it doesn't have a first character `word[0]`. If you read the error message:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

… that's what it's telling you. The problem isn't that you don't have a string, it's that you have a string that isn't big enough to have a first character.

---

What you want to do here is either check for the empty string before asking for its first character:

```
if word and word[0] >= 'h':
    print(word.upper())
    word = ''
else:
    word = ''
```

… or handle the `IndexError`:

```
try:
    if word[0] >= 'h':
        print(word.upper())
        word = ''
    else:
        word = ''
except IndexError:
    word = ''
```

Normally, in Python, it's more idiomatic to just `try` something and handle errors ([Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp), as opposed to [Look Before You Leap](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl)), but in some cases it's going to be more readable to check first, and I think this is one of those cases.

Comment: why not doing `word=''` in the end instead of in all the branches?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That’s a good improvement to the OP’s code, but it’s not relevant to the problem, and I don’t like making extra changes without explaining them. If you think it’s important enough to add as a side note at the end, I can do that (or just edit it yourself—I’m sure you can explain “DRY” in one line at least as well as I can).

Comment: Thanks guys I am able to understand this now